# Syntax error in ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

When traced requests using Fiddler, i'm seeing **HTTP 302 error** code for `WebResource.axd` and `ScriptResource.axd`.. and this problem occurs randomly...

The same web application works good in all other env. I'm using asp.net v3.5.. IIS 7.5 Windows Server 2008.. Any General info on why im getting 302?..

Other errors are `ASP.NET Ajax Client-side framework failed to load, WebForm_PostBackOptions is undefined, Sys is Undefined`.. No links in the page is working. Already done some suggestions in several posts like re-installation of framework, script resource handlers are in place. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Solved!!! This helped me in achieving this : 
http://www.rosshawkins.net/archive/2006/10/08/webresource.axd.aspx

The problem was i missed MachineKey tag. Now it is working perfectly.. Hope this helps someone..